# Prevent deferred execution of extension method or predicate in where cause c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Basically I am creating an extension/predicate method to Mimic .contains behavior

NHibernate Query

```
var query = currentSession.Query<MyEntity>().Where(x => Ids.In("|" + x.Id.ToString() + "|")).Select(y=> y);
```

In the above query `.In` is my extension method.

The above query executes in a deferred manner for extension method /predicate which cause error, but the same query when used with .Contains executes without any problems. Also my extension method or predicate break point is never hit due to deferred execution by Linq.

```
var query = currentSession.Query<MyEntity>().Where(x => Ids.Contains("|" + x.Id.ToString() + "|")).Select(y=> y);
```

I have seen some suggestions where using `.toList()` would make it execute immediately , but I cant use that because I am just forming a query here which will be executed later.

Comment: Then use `Contains`, otherwise you will need third party extensions like `LINQKit`.

Comment: Your LINQ statement is actually building an expression tree that is later parsed and converted to equivalent SQL by the LINQ-to-Entities database provider. That mapping only supports a finite number of operators and function calls, such as `.Contains()`. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#miscellaneous-functions) for EF-Core details. (Your nhibernate environment my be different.) In general, user defined functions cannot be translated.

Comment: ... However, you might be able to define an extension function like `.WhereIn()` that implements your custom logic by adding supported elements to the expression tree, but that is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Svyatoslav Danyliv I was able to achieve what I want with LinqKit

```
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria = p => Ids.Contains("|" + x.Id.ToString() + "|");
        
    var query = currentSession.Query<MyEntity>().Where(criteria.Expand()).Select(y=> y);
```